# How to check if one of two before_filters pass (Rails)? before_filter :check1 || before_filter :check2 ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I have check_feature method in application_controller.rb

```
  def self.check_feature(feature, options = {})
    before_filter(options) { |controller| controller.check_feature_now(feature) }
  end

  def check_feature_now(feature)
    raise MyError.new(401, I18n.t('exception.feature_not_enabled'), ErrorCodes::FEATURE_NOT_ENABLED) unless feature_enabled?(feature)
  end
```

And I'm using this as a filter (before_filter).

In my controller I wanna say something, like at least one of the two features enabled to access the controller.

If I do something like:

```
check_feature :feature1
check_feature :feature2
```

I'll need feature1 AND feature2 enabled to pass the filter.

I want something like:

```
check_feature :feature1 || check_feature :feature2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Controller instance variables? Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413539/hidden-instance-variables-in-before-filter-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper that will be aware of multiple features. Something along these lines:

```
def self.require_one_of(*features, options = {})
  before_filter(options) do |controller|
    unless features.any?{|f| controller.feature_enabled?(f)}
      raise MyError.new(401, I18n.t('exception.feature_not_enabled'), ErrorCodes::FEATURE_NOT_ENABLED)
    end

  end
end


# then
require_one_of :feature1, :feature2
```